# What would be the MYSQL query to get the records without dulicate key

Tags: mysql

I am writing a **MYSQL** query to get the resulted value without duplicate values. Below is my output,

```
EnquiryNo, ClientName, State,   City,   OrderNo, OrderDate, ItemName,  Qty.
1 ,        xxxx ,      MH,      Mumbai,     1 ,   1/1/2000,  Item1,     2
1 ,        xxxx ,      MH,      Mumbai,     1 ,   1/1/2000,  Item2,     5
22 ,        xxxx ,     MH,      Mumbai,     2 ,   1/1/2001,  Item6,    15
22 ,        xxxx ,     MH,      Mumbai,     2 ,   1/1/2001,  Item7,    20
30 ,        YYYY ,     MP,      Bhopal,    45 ,   1/1/2005,  Item10,    2
30,         YYYY ,     MP,      Bhopal,    45 ,   1/1/2005,  Item11,    1
30,         YYYY ,     MH,      Pune,      46 ,   1/1/2005,  Item11,    1
```

I want to modify SQL query such that it can output as below.

```
EnquiryNo, ClientName, State,   City,   OrderNo, OrderDate, ItemName,  Qty.
1 ,        xxxx ,      MH,      Mumbai,     1 ,   1/1/2000,  Item1,     2
           xxxx ,      MH,      Mumbai,     1 ,   1/1/2000,  Item2,     5
22 ,       xxxx ,      MH,      Mumbai,     2 ,   1/1/2001,  Item6,    15
       xxxx ,      MH,      Mumbai,     2 ,   1/1/2001,  Item7,    20
30 ,       YYYY ,      MP,      Bhopal,    45 ,   1/1/2005,  Item10,    2
       YYYY ,      MP,      Bhopal,    45 ,   1/1/2005,  Item11,    1
       YYYY ,      MH,      Pune,      46 ,   1/1/2005,  Item11,    1
```

For Your reference here is the query to create and insert query,

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
  EnquiryNo VARCHAR (100),
  ClientName VARCHAR (100),
  State VARCHAR (100),
  City VARCHAR (100),
  OrderNo VARCHAR (100),
  OrderDate VARCHAR (100),
  ItemName VARCHAR (100),
  Qty VARCHAR (100)
) ;

INSERT into temp
select '1' , 'xxxx', 'MH', 'Mumbai', '1' ,'1/1/2000', 'Item1','2'
union all select '1' , 'xxxx' , 'MH', 'Mumbai', '1' , '1/1/2000',    'Item2','5'
union all select '22' , 'xxxx' , 'MH', 'Mumbai', '2' , '1/1/2001','Item6','15'
union all select '22' , 'xxxx' , 'MH', 'Mumbai', '2' ,    '1/1/2001',    'Item7',   '20'
union all select '30' , 'YYYY' , 'MP', 'Bhopal', '45' ,   '1/1/2005',    'Item10',  '2'
union all select '30' , 'YYYY' , 'MP', 'Bhopal', '45' ,   '1/1/2005',    'Item11',  '1'
union all select '30', 'YYYY' , 'MH', 'Pune',   '46' ,   '1/1/2005',    'Item11',  '1';

SELECT * FROM temp;
```

Comment: Your expected result contains all data so there is no chance of group by or distict. Its probably more of display rather than the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result is impossible in SQL, because not all rows have the same number of columns. You will have to use code on the view-side to create what you want.

By the way, you can also insert multiple records like this:

```
INSERT INTO temp (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2), (val3,val4)
```

no need for a subselect and `UNION`.

Comment: Hi Bart, Thanks for your response, But I have gone through another site. This is possible using SQL using partition .  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a6e97408-aa97-48ec-a559-b9071068432b/how-to-write-a-sql-statement-which-can-hide-duplicate-values-during-query-output?forum=transactsql

Comment: Just because it is possible, does not mean it is wise.

Comment: Also, I'd say the suggested result is NOT what you ask for. In your question, you ask for rows with a different column count (I don't see the `NULL` values in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Case when ROW_NUMBER > 1 Then NULL else EnquiryNo End, ClientName,State,City,OrderNo,OrderDate,ItemName,Qty 
FROM 
(
SELECT  EnquiryNo,ClientName,State,City,OrderNo,OrderDate,ItemName,Qty,
        @i := if(@lastGroupID != EnquiryNo, 1, @i + 1) as row_number,
        @lastGroupID := EnquiryNo
FROM temp,
  (select @i := 0) row_number_table,
  (select @lastGroupID := null) group_id_table
ORDER BY EnquiryNo
) AS T
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58055/18)